# What Beamer theme is used in Boyd's Convex Optimization slides?

Tags: beamer, themes, powerdot

I really like the theme that is used here:

http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxslides.pdf
Can someone identify the name of the theme?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Is this a theme? That look like the plain beamer presentation with a small modifications to fonts and colors.

Comment: The most common (default) Beamer themes can be found on [www.hartwork.org](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/). It seems that those slides are based on the user's own customized template, as @m0nhawk suggests.

Comment: On second thought, looking at the theme matrix, it looks very similar to Pittsburgh with Dove/Seagull as the color scheme. I'm not sure what the font is.

Comment: It's a `powerdot` (or something that predates `beamer`) theme if I remember correctly, because I asked him once.

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest thing be to e-mail Stephen Boyd and just ask him (and then tell us what he said)?

Comment: Just came across this thread and in case anyone else is still looking for this:
<br>
Boyd shares his LaTex templates on his [Convex Optimization class website](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/latex_templates/). He has LaTex templates for his general notes, slides and posters along with PDFs of those templates.
<br>

Answer (score 7):

I do not know how Boyd produced his slides (he might have used `powerdot`, according to percusse's comment above), but I largely based my lecture template on his, because I like its sober style and printer-friendliness.

The following code might require some additional tweaks to exactly replicate Boyd's template. Note, in particular, that

1. the original template has a different paper size, which I didn't bother matching (even though the ratio in my template is the same);
2. The title page is slightly different from Boyd's.
3. I changed the item symbol to shaded grey balls, which I find easier on the eye than plain black ones.

However, I think my template should get you halfway there.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[
    smaller,
    %handout,
]{beamer}

% -------- Packages ---------
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


% ----- Beamer tweaks -----
\let\Tiny=\tiny % to prevent warnings from LaTeX (due to Beamer)
\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{default}}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\linespread{1.5}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=30pt}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=30pt}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
\setlength{\leftmargini}{1.2em}
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{1em}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball unnumbered]
\AtBeginSection[]{ 
  \begin{frame}[handout:0]
    \frametitle{Contents} 
    \tableofcontents[currentsection] 
  \end{frame} 
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1} 
} 
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\normalsize}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \begin{centering}
        \large      
        \textbf{\insertframetitle}
        \par
    \end{centering}
}

% ----- Redefinition of frame (to reset footnote numbering at each frame) -----
\let\oldframe\frame                         % backup old frame
\let\endoldframe\endframe                   % backup old endframe
\renewenvironment{frame}{%
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}\oldframe%
}{\endoldframe}                             % Reset the footnote counter at each frame


% ----- Footnote symbols -----
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}   


% ----- Handout settings -----
\mode<handout>{\usetheme{default}}
\mode<handout>{\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm, landscape]}
\mode<handout>{\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}}
\mode<handout>{\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}}
\mode<handout>{\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}}
\mode<handout>{\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}}


% ----- fancyhdr -----
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % No header
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{ % Footer
    \leavevmode
    \vskip0pt
    \hbox{ 
        % left
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{title in head/foot}
        \hspace*{25pt}
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\textcolor{gray}{\inserttitle}
    \end{beamercolorbox}

    % right
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{page number in head/foot}
            \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\arabic{lectnum}-\insertpagenumber{}
        \hspace*{30pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
    \vskip17pt 
}


\newcounter{lectnum}        % Lecture counter
\setcounter{lectnum}{99}    % lecture counter
\title{my title}            % topic from syllabus
\subtitle[EE2376234]{Convex Optimization}
\author{Jubobs}
\institute[JA]{Jubobs academy}
\date{}



\begin{document}
% ----- Title Page -----
{% these braces define the local group associated to the titlepage

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{ % header
    \leavevmode
    \vskip20pt
    \hbox{
    % left
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subtitle in head/foot}
            \hspace*{25pt}
            \usebeamerfont{subtitle in head/foot}\insertshortsubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}

    % center
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}
        % nothing
    \end{beamercolorbox}

    % right
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.32\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{institute in head/foot}
            \hfill
            \usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\insertinstitute
            \hspace*{30pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{ % footer
    \leavevmode
    \vskip0pt%
    \hbox{
    % left
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{author in head/foot}
        \hspace*{25pt}
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}

    % center
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\texttt{jubobsl@jubobs.com}
    \end{beamercolorbox}

    % right
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{page number in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\textcolor{black}{\arabic{lectnum}-\insertpagenumber{}}
        \hspace*{30pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
    \vskip17pt
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
    \begin{center}
    %\vspace{-3mm}
    {\large \textbf{Lecture~\arabic{lectnum}}}\\
    {\Large \textbf{\inserttitle}}
    \end{center}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}  

} 

%
\section{Introduction}  

    %
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Objectives}
        By the end of this lecture, you should
        \begin{itemize}
            \item be able to solve a big nonconvex QCQP without a computer
            \item be a Matlab and Python guru
            \item know CVX like the back of your hand   
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}  

\section{Linear systems}

\section{Convex optimization}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aaargh control people invading TeX.SE... Ruuuun

Comment: @percusse Actually, in [one of his lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1A734g96Npk#t=0m53s), Boyd pokes fun at people who use the term "control community" :) My bet is that Boyd was referring to Maciejowski, whose book on MPC contains the term "control community".

Comment: Don't get me started on control theory :)